What is grammatical value?
According to a publication by Butte College, Oroville, CA,


Coordinating and correlative conjunctions both link elements of equal grammatical value.


What does "grammatical value" mean?
And does "equal grammatical value" linked by either type of these conjunctions correspond to parallelism in sentence structure?

Hello, Quốc Anh Phạm. Please explain where you found this precept (an attribution and hyperlink). It's not that the statement is suspect, but it helps to know if terminology is specific to a certain author / certain authors, rather than universally adopted.

Hello. It is this one: https://www.butte.edu/departments/cas/tipsheets/grammar/conjunctions.html

Grammatical value means function: subject, object, predicator, modifier, complement, etc.
Parallelism is another issue, that would be similarity of phrase or clause or word type in a coordination or other construction where two or more items follow closely upon one another and would be expected to have the same form.

I like [eating cookies [and to bake cakes]].

This is what is known as a parallelism error because the complements to like are in coordination, but have two different forms,  -ing clause vs to-infinitival clause, where we would expect the same. Either of the following is fine:

I like to eat cookies and to bake cakes
I like eating cookies and baking cakes.

Though, sometimes parallelism need not be strictly observed.

He was [sweet [but a little bit of a weirdo]].

Here an adjective phrase is in coordination with a noun phrase; both acting as subject-oriented predicative complement to was, but of dissimilar phrase types. They don't satisfy parallelism, but few would find fault with this sentence.

Grammatical values are not just functions; you could add "person", "verbal desinence" and "voice", among others, so as to give a better idea of the wide scope of this term. Making a contrast with lexical value and providing references would be a plus in this explanation.

Humber Liberal Arts Dept of Eng provides a reference of sorts: 'The words, phrases and clauses that are connected by the coordinate conjunctions must be of equal grammatical value. In other words, coordinate conjunctions can connect adjectives, nouns, verbs, prepositional phrases, infinitives, independent clauses, and any other structures that share the same grammatical form.'

@LPH 'He had always regretted that he was born before electricity became widely available' shows acceptable formal mismatch of timeframe markers. It's good that DW256 gives an example where parallelism isn't seen as inviolate.

'It was huge and a nightmare' doesn't work well, while 'It was huge', 'He was a nightmare', and 'It was huge and a nightmare to behold' all do. Possibly semantically  constrained (*/?'He was huge and a philatelist.') but perhaps there's more going on.

There's two issues here. One is what do coordinating conjunctions actually coordinate. The other is what does the linked-to page use the term 'grammatical value' to refer to. Your post is the correct answer to the first question. Sadly, however, the linked to page is talking about phrases from the same phrasal category, not phrases fro the same syntactic function.
